# File reading and writing java help please

Tags: java

When working with files in Java or any programming language? Why must you close files when you are done processing them?

I'm assuming you have to close it because the program wouldn't stop writing and the file wouldn't be written properly?

Comment: You don't close files, you close InputStreams and OutputStreams.

Comment: You could prevent other processes from reading/writing to the files. They also consume resources (within the JVM and the OS) which you will want to release when you no longer need them

Answer (score 1):

That is largely correct for `Stream`(s) not `File`. And, more formally the output buffer isn't fully [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)ed until you [`OutputStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29) actually *releases any system resources associated with this stream*.

Comment: You can `flush` without `close`

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but `close()` also releases the system resources.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must you close files when you are done processing them?

To tell the file system that you are done processing them.

That can have all sorts of consequences: finally synching the file to disc; updating the directory meta-data; making the file accessible to other processes ...

Comment: You've forgotten that operating systems have limited resources available. This includes file descriptors which are used to reference to files. Thus, not freeing those resources will result in no more file handles available rendering you unable to open any file anymore.

Answer (score -1):

The best way for reading and writing file by using I/O streams and after that use for loop for processing streams because loop will automatically stop whole process after completion.
Another way is that use I/O streams and after processing stop streams manually.